# Do the attributes in python classes change value if given the same name?

Tags: python, oop

I am learning Python OOP programming and I was running this little script:

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, first, last):

        self.first = first
        self.last = last

emp1 = Employee("Fede", "Cuci")

print emp1.first
print emp1.last
```

Everything worked fine, until I noticed that when I created a method with the same attributes, and printed them out, it would take those values instead:

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, first, last):

        self.first = first
        self.last = last

    def fullname(self, first, last):

        self.first = first
        self.last = last

    def other_fullname(self, first, last):

        self.first = first
        self.last = last


emp1 = Employee("Fede", "Cuci")
emp1.fullname("Fede2", "Cuci2")
emp1.other_fullname("Fede3", "Cuci3")

print emp1.first
print emp1.last
```

And then I noticed that it would always print out the last method called. Does this mean that you should name the attributes differently in each class and use this technique just to update the attribute's value, or have I done something wrong in my code?

I thought that by putting `"self"` in each method, would make the attribute unique to that specific method, not that if I tried to print out that attribute again, it would update it's value based on which method I called last...

Please correct me if I am wrong,
Thanks in advance,

Fede

Comment: `self` is the current instance. It is not unique to each method, no. You manipulate the current state of the instance with methods, that state is *meant* to be shared between those methods.

Comment: So what did you think those last two lines would *do*? Those are still the same attributes stored on the instance. Which one of the methods would you have expected to have been responsible for those attributes?

Comment: So is that the way to change the value of self in that instance? @MartijnPieters

Comment: Not sure what you mean; the value of the `self` variable is the instance of Employee you are working with, the object that the method was called on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` is a reference to the current instance. Attributes on that instance are not unique to each method, no. The whole point of methods is to be able to manipulate that state of the instance.

Print those two attributes after each method call, and you'll see they change with each method manipulating those attributes:

```
>>> emp1 = Employee("Fede", "Cuci")
>>> emp1.first
'Fede'
>>> emp1.last
'Cuci'
>>> emp1.fullname("Fede2", "Cuci2")
>>> emp1.first
'Fede2'
>>> emp1.last
'Cuci2'
>>> emp1.other_fullname("Fede3", "Cuci3")
>>> emp1.first
'Fede3'
>>> emp1.last
'Cuci3'
```

So yes, if each method needs to have their own state tied to the instance, you'll need to use unique names.

If attributes were unique to each method, you could never have two different methods operate on the same piece of information.

Comment: Thank you, your answer was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Self is the instance of the class.  If you want each method to store its own name in the object you will need to give it a unique attribute.

For example

```
def fullname(self, first, last):

    self.fullNameFirst = first
    self.fullNameLast = last
```